# Height of child element as percentage of parent element

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` tag inside the `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation, I want to make height of my `EditText` as percentage of parent `LinearLayout's` height. How can this be achieved?

Please don't suggest `layout_weight` attribute as it will be used to control child elements width not height.

Comment: I suggest you create a custom layout where you will handle the children sizes, consider create you own attributes to set the percents values.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom layout that resizes its children to the correct percentages, which is probably the best solution.

Or you could use `layout_weight` and wrap the `EditText` in another `LinearLayout`, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="one"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="two"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Percentages within a LinearLayout are very easy.

Give your view a weight

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="one"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've set the height of the two textViews to 0, but the layout_weight says to make one 50% of the LinearLayout and the other 25% the height of the layout.